# Radon-Nikodym: Integrability?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $\lambda:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}_+$ and $\kappa:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}_+$ be finite measures on $\Omega$.

Then by Radon-Nikodym:
$$\kappa(E)\leq L\cdot\lambda(E)\quad(\forall E\in\Sigma)\implies\kappa(E)=\int_Ehd\lambda \quad(\forall E\in\Sigma)$$
for some representative $0\leq h\leq L$.

Now, what about integrability:
$$f\in L(\kappa)\iff f\in L(\lambda)$$

So far I got that:
$$\int|f|d\kappa=\int|f|\cdot|h|d\lambda\leq L\int|f|d\lambda$$
which proves one inclusion...

Comment: I missed the obvious: For the case $h\equiv 0$ this can't be true if $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true:
$$f\in L^1(\kappa)\iff f\in L^1(\lambda).$$

However, from $\kappa(E)\le c\lambda(E)$, you can deduce that

$$
f\in L^1(\lambda)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad f\in L^1(\kappa).
$$